# Чтение файла средствами PHP

Tags: php

Возможно ли с помощью `fread` либо другой функции прочитать файл с расширением `php`? `include` и `require` не предлагать, нужно прочитать строки из файла в переменную.

Answer (score 2):

Чтение файла полностью:

```
$text = file_get_contents('file.php');
```

Или построчно:

```
$handle = fopen('file.php', "r");

if ($handle) {
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
        // $buffer содержит строку из файла целиком
    }
    if (!feof($handle)) {
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Учтите, что файл загружается в память. При большом файле - источнике можно легко поймать лимит по памяти. А если выполнять код через веб-сервер, то и тайм лимит.

Вообще файл с расширением .php никак не отличается от файла с расширением .txt.

Попробуйте еще так

```
$tmpFile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'php');
copy('varlib.php', $tmpFile);
echo file_get_contents($tmpFile);
unlink($tmpFile);
```

Comment: А вообще вопрос легко гуглится.

Comment: да , но вот тут произошла какая - то ошибка , fread читает .txt файлы , а вот .php файлы вовсе не отображает построчно , он их будто интерпретирует , а не читает как "текст"

Comment: Покажите код. У меня сегодня не работает дар ясновидения. file_get_contents читает .php?

Comment: $text = file_get_contents('varlib.php');
echo $text;

Comment: он тоже не читает , права на файл все выставлены , имя тоже верное

Comment: Так дайте же посмотреть код. file_exists('varlib.php') что вернет? Ошибки отображаются (display_errors)?

Comment: @S1lllver Похоже `echo` интерпретирует ваш код, сделайте так `echo htmlspecialchars($text);` и будет вам счастье.

Comment: Спасибо большое , сработало , я так и думал что он интерпретирует а вот про htmlspecialchars совсем не догодался , постоянно смотрю куда - то далеко а ответ прямо перед глазами )

Comment: @S1lllver для технической точности замечу, не echo интерпретирует (это невозможно), а браузер интерпретирует голый вывод как html-код

Comment: это понятно , но в данном случае разговор шел про то что , при выводе этого текста через echo . он не показывал его как строку , а выполнял код , вот собственно почему и написали echo :)
но спасибо за отзыв)